# I am facing some issues while using arduino working with memory card and speaker, please help me

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

This is the code I wrote:
I set the pins given accordingly I checked my ultrasonic sensors, transistor, and resistors are in working condition. CS (in code denoted as chipset) is pinned in pin 10, resistor to 9, and that resistor is connected to the transistor, and then it is connected to the speaker.

```
#define trigPin1 3
#define echoPin1 2
#define trigPin2 4
#define echoPin2 5
#define trigPin3 7
#define echoPin3 8
#define cs 10
#include "SD.h"
#include "TMRpcm.h"
#include "SPI.h"

TMRpcm tmrpcm;


long duration, distance, RightSensor, BackSensor, FrontSensor, LeftSensor;

void setup()
{
  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(cs))
  {
    Serial.println("SD fail");
  }
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);
  RightSensor = distance;
  tmrpcm.setVolume(6);
  if (RightSensor > 10)
  {
    tmrpcm.play("RightFormatted.wav");
  }
  
  SonarSensor(trigPin2, echoPin2);
  LeftSensor = distance;
  if (LeftSensor > 10)
  {
    tmrpcm.play("LeftFormatted.wav");
  }
 
  SonarSensor(trigPin3, echoPin3);
  FrontSensor = distance;
  if (FrontSensor > 10)
  {
    tmrpcm.play("FrontFormatted.wav");
  }
  

  Serial.println(LeftSensor);
  Serial.println(" - ");
  Serial.print(FrontSensor);
  Serial.print(" - ");
  Serial.println(RightSensor);
}

void SonarSensor(int trigPin, int echoPin)
{
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;

}
```

The error I am getting is:
[Error of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2V5L.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing the name of the .wav file directly inside the `.play` method, create a `const char` variable to assign the name(s):

```
const char* audio1= "RightFormatted.wav";
```

then you can use it as:#

```
tmrpcm.play(audio1);
```

However, based on the examples from the library, you do not need the file extension, but I might be wrong in this regard.

Try first my proposal and please report your results